# How to make a file show up in the Downloads App?

Tags: downloading

I have copied a file to the Downloads folder with the *File Manager* App. But when I open the *Downloads* App, the file doesn't show up.

The Downloads folder is definately the right one: I've deleted a file in the *Downloads* App and could wittness its disappearance in the Downloads folder in the *File Manager* App.

Does the *Downloads* app register downloads somehow and only shows files that have come to the Downloads folder the right way by some *Downloads* App standard?

**Update:**

I renamed a file in the Downloads folder to a filename, that already showed up in the *Downloads* App. That did work, I could open the file from the *Downloads* App.

Seems very strange to me...

My phone is a LANIX Ilium LT500 on Android 5.1.

**Update 2:**

Even a reboot of the phone could not make the *Downloads* App show all files in the Downloads folder...

Comment: Edit `/data/data/com.android.providers.downloads/databases/downloads.db`.

Comment: nothing strange on this behavior. the downloads app is not related to files. it's just a kind of notifications history, similar to your pc's webbrowser download history